# Deseo guardar toda mi información en arrays a la hora de darle al botón "save"

Tags: c#

Aquí está la parte de código donde muestro qeé cosas quiero guardar, mi fin es guardar todos esos datos en un array. He intentado con varias maneras de hacerlo a mi gusto pero no me dan resultado. ¿Algún consejo o alguna forma de hacerlo que pueda funcionar?

```
namespace SmartGYM
{
    public partial class New_Member : Form
    {
        public New_Member()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fname = txtFirstName.Text;
            string lname = txtLastName.Text;

            string gender = "";

            bool isCraked = radioButton1.Checked;

            if (isCraked)
            {
                gender = radioButton1.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                gender = radioButton2.Text;
            }

            String dob = dateTimePickerDBO.Text;
            Int64 mobile = Int64.Parse(txtMobile.Text);
            string email = txtEmail.Text;
            string joindate = dateTimePickerJoinDate.Text;
            string gymtime = comboBoxGym.Text;
            string address = txtAddress.Text;
            string membership = comboBoxMembership.Text;

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtFirstName.Clear();
            txtLastName.Clear();

            radioButton1.Checked = false;
            radioButton2.Checked = false;

            txtMobile.Clear();
            txtEmail.Clear();

            comboBoxGym.ResetText();
            comboBoxMembership.ResetText();
            txtAddress.Clear();

            dateTimePickerDBO.Value = DateTime.Now;
            dateTimePickerJoinDate.Value = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, en ningún lado veo el array donde lo quieres guardar, pero puedes tener una instancia de un array en la clase y te puedes crear una clase con las propiedades que deseas guardar, así tienes una List<NombreClase> y puedes ir añadiendo los objetos con los datos que quieres.

Answer (score 0):

Deberias poner esto en el botón que deseas guardar la información

Primero debes declarar el array.

```
string[] GuardarDatos = new  string[10] //Veo 10 valores en tus txt
//Acá deberias ingresar la información de los txt al Array, hay muchas formas. 
//Lo hare de la forma más facil aunque tambien puede ser la forma más larga. 
GuardarDatos[0] = fname ; 
GuardarDatos[1] = lname;
GuardarDatos[2] = gender;
GuardarDatos[3] = dob.ToString();
GuardarDatos[4] = mobile.ToString();
GuardarDatos[5] = email;
GuardarDatos[6] = joindate;
GuardarDatos[7] = gymtime;
GuardarDatos[8] = address;
GuardarDatos[9] = membership;

//Si quieres recorrer el array es así 
for(int i = 0; i<10 ; i++ )
{
Console.Writeline("Valor en el arreglo" + GuardarDatos[i].ToString())
}
```

Espero ser claro y que esto sea de tu ayuda.